# Case insensitive unicode collation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation, case-insensitive

I've got a database where we store usernames with a capital first letter of each name -- ie, IsaacSparling.  I'm trying to do case insensitive autocomplete against my MySQL (v5.1.46) db.  Table has a charset of UTF8 and a collation of utf8_unicode_ci.  I've done these tests against the utf8_general_ci collation as well.

Plain ASCII text works fine:

```
mysql> select username from users where username like 'j%';
+----------------+
| username       |
+----------------+
| J********      |
| J***********   |
| J************* |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select username from users where username like 'J%';
+----------------+
| username       |
+----------------+
| J********      |
| J***********   |
| J************* |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(names redacted, but they're there).

However, when I try to do the same for unicode characters outside the ASCII set, no such luck:

```
mysql> select username from users where username like 'ø%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select username from users where username like 'Ø%';
+-------------+
| username    |
+-------------+
| Ø*********  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Some investigation has lead me to this:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19567  (tl;dr, this is a known bug with the unicode collations, and fixing it is at 'new feature' priority -- ie, won't be finished in any reasonable timeframe).

Has anybody discovered any effective workarounds that allow for case-insensitive searching for unicode characters in MySQL?  Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question! As far as I understand the bug, it has nothing to do with your problem though? It seems to be about accent sensitivity `a` => `á`

Comment: Can you check whether `where LOWER(username) LIKE 'ø%'` works? It's likely to be subject to the same behaviour but if it isn't, it might serve as a workaround

Comment: mysql> select 1 from users where LOWER(username) LIKE 'ø%';
    Empty set (0.00 sec)
No dice.  It seems like case transition for unicode characters outside the ascii set is totally borked.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me with version 5.1.42-community

Maybe your mysql client did not send the unicode characters properly. I tested with sqlYog and it worked just fine with both utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci collations

Answer (score 0):

IF what you care about is being able to order the field values by the text without caring if it is in upper or lower case I think the best thing you can do is when addressing the field instead of typing just `username`, type `LOWER(username) username` and then you can perfectly use an order by that field calling it by its name

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CONVERT?  Something like

```
WHERE `lastname` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 'ø%' USING latin1 )
```

might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same problem using the query

```
show variables like '%char%';
```

My character_set_client was set to 'utf8', but character_set_connection and character_set_results were set to 'latin1'. Thus, the functions UPPER, LOWER, LIKE did not work as expected.

I just inserted the line

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

right after connection to get the case-insensitive searching work.